# AngularJS: Prevent displaying the last separator when repeating multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Question**: What is the most elegant way to ensure the last separator on each line is never shown?

```
11|18|3|8|12|1|22|31|61|
11:18:3:8:12:1:22:31:
11,18,3,8,12,61,
1 22 31
```

Note that the data originates from three different arrays, e.g., the data for line 1 is defined as:

```
$scope.numbers = [11,18,3,8,12];
$scope.specialNumbers = [1,22,31];
$scope.additionalNumbers = [61];
```

I would like to see a more elegant/angular way, than just finding the last `<li>` and remove separator using `$element.find`, or similar.

I created a little [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da4Loops/1/) example to demonstrate the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution, using the proposed `$last` check (only once) in combination with `Array.concat`, which is supported in Angular expressions and thus supports bindings. However, to correctly repeat literals, you need to moreover `track by $index`.

```
"<li ng-repeat='num in numbers.concat(specialNumbers,additionalNumbers) " +
               "track by $index'>" +
    "<span>{{ num }}</span><span ng-if='!$last'>{{ separator }}</span>" + 
"</li>"
```

Comment: Btw., if you omit the `track by` Angular throws an error and tells you to consider using `track by`. You can (and should always) check the browsers console output in your Fiddles to learn why some code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/d0ogyfon/

Use Kosta's `$last` and just concat the lists and iterate once?

```
    var html = "<ul>" +
                "<li ng-repeat='num in numbers.concat(specialNumbers, additionalNumbers)'>" +
    "<span ng-if='!$last'>{{ num }}{{ separator }}</span>" + 
    "<span ng-if='$last'>{{ num }}</span>" + 
                "</li>" +

           "</ul>";
```

Comment: Nice solution, but unfortunately in that way, bindings will stop to work (when numbers changes, no re-rendering). https://jsfiddle.net/d0ogyfon/1/

Answer (score 2):

And, just for fun, how about a CSS-based solution:

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/da4Loops/3/)

**CSS:**

```
li.pipe:not(:last-child):after {
    content: '| ';
}
li.colon:not(:last-child):after {
    content: ': ';
}
li.comma:not(:last-child):after {
    content: ', ';
}
li.space:not(:last-child):after {
    content: ' ';
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="numset1">
    <div test numbers="numbers" special-numbers="specialNumbers" additional-numbers="additionalNumbers" separator-class="pipe"></div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="numset2">
    <div test numbers="numbers" special-numbers="specialNumbers" additional-numbers="additionalNumbers" separator-class="colon"></div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="numset3">
    <div test numbers="numbers" special-numbers="specialNumbers" additional-numbers="additionalNumbers" separator-class="comma"></div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="numset4">
    <div test numbers="numbers" special-numbers="specialNumbers" additional-numbers="additionalNumbers" separator-class="space"></div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive("test",function(){
    var html = 
        "<ul>" +
        "<li class='{{separator}}' ng-repeat='num in numbers'>{{ num }}</li>" +
            "<li class='{{separator}}' ng-repeat='num in specialNumbers'>{{ num }}</li>" +
            "<li class='{{separator}}' ng-repeat='num in additionalNumbers'>{{ num }}</li>" +
        "</ul>";
    
    return {
        template: html,
        scope: {
            separator: "@separatorClass",
            numbers: "=",
            specialNumbers: "=",
            additionalNumbers: "="
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Looks promising. I think it will not work in IE8, but otherwise I like it (we are still support IE 8).

Comment: You're correct. IE8 supports first-child, but not last-child pseudo class selectors.  Damn you Microsoft ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `$last` element:

```
"<li ng-repeat='num in additionalNumbers'>" +
     "<span ng-if='!$last'>{{ num }}{{ separator }}</span>" + 
     "<span ng-if='$last'>{{ num }}</span>" + 
"</li>"
```

Comment: It will not work with numset2 and numset4 in example.